# Is my algorithm a linear time

Tags: python, algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o, time-complexity

```
# given an array, it solves sum of elements in it, 
# args: array, initial and final indices
# Returns: sum of elements
def ArrayTot (arr, low, high):
    return sum( arr[low : high+1] )

# Is this linear time?
# args: array, initial and final indices
# returns: Max possible value in sub-array.
def MaxSubArray (arr, low, high):
    # max value of sub-array
    TotalArray = 0
    # starts iterating arr from left - right i.e., arr[low, j]
    for j in xrange(low, high+1):
        # finds sum of sub array arr[low,j]
        tot = ArrayTot (arr, low, j)
        # Iterates the sub-array arr[low,j] so as to find any other possible arr[i,j] which results max value
        for i in xrange(low, j+1):
            SubArrTot = ArrayTot(arr, i, j)
            if SubArrTot >= tot:
                tot = SubArrTot
        if tot >= TotalArray:
            TotalArray = tot
    return TotalArray

arr = [13,-3,-25,20,-3,-16,-23,18,20,-7,12,-5,-22,15,-4,7]
low = 0
high = 15

print MaxSubArray(arr, low, high)
```

I am learning algorithms (Book: Introduction to Algorithms).. So, I am supposed to find a sub-array in a given array which constitutes maximum sum.. Yeah, a Non-recursive, linear time algorithm..

This is what I have done (shown above).. But In my solution, there is a `for` loop inside a `for` loop and both iterates 'n' terms..

If I am not wrong, it should be `O(n^2)` which is not linear! In that case, how should I probably solve it?

Comment: You could try timing your code to see how the time depends on the array length.

Comment: @GWWW Not really. I actually study Biotech .. so, I study CS myself at home

Comment: @DennisRitchie you could also consider posting this one http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, since you just want someone to look at your code, rather than have a concrete question to ask

Answer (score 5):

This is certainly not a linear solution. One of the linear-time algorithms that solve this problem is known as  the [Kadane's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem).

Even just this bit of code

```
for j in xrange(low, high+1):
    tot = ArrayTot (arr, low, j)
```

already has `Theta(n^2)` time complexity.

Comment: I could have simply used a python function...`sum(array)`.. then this could be approximated to linear time

Comment: @DennisRitchie No, `sum` is linear time too.

Comment: The first step in optimizing **this** algorithm would be to memorize the sums of the subarrays in a table and not recalculate them every time. This would make it `O(n^2)` instead of `O(n^3)` it takes now. This is still slower than the Kadane's algorithm, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that it is not even 0(n^2).. it is O(n^3). `ArrayTot(arr, i, j)` is O(n), and it is in the i-loop which is inside the j-loop.

But you can optimize `ArrayTot(arr, i, j)` to O(1) by using a sum array, namely, range_sum[1..n], where `range_sum[1] = arr[1]`, `range_sum[i+1] = range_sum[i] + arr[i+1], i>0`, then we can calculate `ArrayTot(arr, i, j)` in O(1) time, just use `range_sum[j]-range_sum[i-1]`.

But you still cannot get O(n) with your method, this is a very classic DP problem, just google it.

Comment: @DennisRitchie, the python's implementation of sum is in linear time, don't rely on it.

Comment: for writing sum array, we need O(n)!

Comment: @DennisRitchie, yes, but you'll have to do it for only once.